# Weird space on page with slick slider?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I'm creating a website with slick slider and have got the plugin working smoothly, but there is a weird space on the left that is causing the site to have a horizontal slider. I have tried maxing out the viewports of the containers but to no avail? Is there a way to remove this white space so that there is no horizontal slider.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.forss').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '0w',
        slidesToShow: 3.625,
      });
  });
```

```css
// navigation.css

body {
    background-color: #5336F8;
    font-family: Futura PT;
}
ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 3vw;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 3vw 1vw 0 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
}

li {
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}


li a {
    display: block;
    font-weight: lighter;
    float: right;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 0.5vw 0 0.5vw;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.75vw 2vw;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:not(.active):hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #5336F8;
    border: 1px; 
}

.active {
    border: 1px solid white;
}



.logo {
    font-family: Futura PT;
    float: left;
    font-size: 4vw;
    margin: 2vw 5vw 0 3.5vw;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 550;
}

.logo:hover {
    color: #5336F8;
    text-shadow: 1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
}

// style.css


div.slick-slider {
    width:100vw;
}

.forss {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.forss .items {
    width: 30vw;
    height: 35vw;
    margin-top: 7vw;
}

.forss .items img {
    width: 24.840625vw;
    height: 31.25vw;
}

.slick-slide {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    
    transition:transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.slick-slide:focus {
        outline: none;
}

div.slick-track {
    width: 100vw;
}

div.slick-center {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.15);
    transform: scale(1.15);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#arrows {
    width: 1vw;
    height: 1vw;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;

}

.logo {
    font-family: 'Futura-Normal';
    font-size: 4vw;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2vw;
}

.top  {
    position: absolute;
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 100%;
    transition: opacity 0.15s;
}

.top:hover {
    opacity: 0%;
}

.bottom img {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}


input.prev:focus {
    outline-width: 0;
}

input.next:focus {
    outline-width: 0;
}

.add-on {
    font-family: (var(--font));
    font-size: 1.75vw;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 2vw;
    margin-right: 2vw;
    margin-bottom: 1vw;
}

#inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    margin-bottom: 4vw;
}

#centered {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Slider</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!--style.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1T5ZdOkN6sg2weNQkehStYX2mDo1f0ajJ">
<!--navigation.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1IgyMKG47riH_HmnHoPLH16qhI0UtnK34">

</head>

<body>
    <h2 class="logo">The Lowdown.</h2>

    <ul>
        <li><a  href="text.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="#edition">EDITIONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#articles">ARTICLES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
        
      </ul>

    <div class="forss">
        <div class="items">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/FWpLzhw/April-Edition-Overlay.png" class="top" alt="" >
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/FbRKb0dt5bz6QOt34jA7jl43XFkHFQf7T0j3wL6b1Z0zSVMNO2DlWl7UAUoTd_dDvCZFhbW822HYyJJQkgH8K0o2dXUrv5uzZl2qrXYF7UWVqqHVinvAqdqz057ULytRu9IE3N0pIw=w2400" class="bottom" alt="">
        </div> 
        <div class="items">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/FWpLzhw/April-Edition-Overlay.png" class="top" alt="" >
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/h2VBt78/May-Edition-Back.png" class="bottom" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="items">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/FWpLzhw/April-Edition-Overlay.png" class="top" alt="" >
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/FbRKb0dt5bz6QOt34jA7jl43XFkHFQf7T0j3wL6b1Z0zSVMNO2DlWl7UAUoTd_dDvCZFhbW822HYyJJQkgH8K0o2dXUrv5uzZl2qrXYF7UWVqqHVinvAqdqz057ULytRu9IE3N0pIw=w2400" class="bottom" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="items">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/FWpLzhw/April-Edition-Overlay.png" class="top" alt="" >
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/h2VBt78/May-Edition-Back.png" class="bottom" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="items">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/FWpLzhw/April-Edition-Overlay.png" class="top" alt="" >
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/FbRKb0dt5bz6QOt34jA7jl43XFkHFQf7T0j3wL6b1Z0zSVMNO2DlWl7UAUoTd_dDvCZFhbW822HYyJJQkgH8K0o2dXUrv5uzZl2qrXYF7UWVqqHVinvAqdqz057ULytRu9IE3N0pIw=w2400" class="bottom" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="inner">
    <div id="centered">
        <input type="image" name="previous" src="https://i.ibb.co/dt3fngT/previous-arrow.png" class="prev" id="arrows" alt="Tool Tip"><span class="add-on">         READ ME         </span><input type="image" name="next" src="https://i.ibb.co/nL7jtPS/next-arrow.png" class="next" id="arrows" alt="Tool Tip">
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1jzlbwu186Lrp0yF_NIcH9Zk2tSFA2PdL"></script>
```

Comment: hi, I facing the same issue but on the right side, did you fix this one?

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with using the viewport width (vw) for the slideshow elements (slideshow and slide navigation). Since there is padding on the `body` element, the content width will include that, which forces the page width to equal (viewport width + `body` left padding + `body` right padding). I was able to remove the horizontal scrollbar by changing/adding the CSS below:

```
div.slick-slider {
    // width:100vw;
}

#inner {
    width: 100% !important;
    ...
}

body {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    ...
}
```

Note: these changes may not be reflected in the SO preview below. For some reason, I'm not seeing the updates to the `.slick-slider` and `body` CSS reflected there.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.forss').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '0w',
        slidesToShow: 3.625,
      });
  });
```

```css
// navigation.css

body {
    background-color: #5336F8;
    font-family: Futura PT;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 3vw;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 3vw 1vw 0 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
}

li {
    float: right;
    font-size: 1.5vw;
}


li a {
    display: block;
    font-weight: lighter;
    float: right;
    color: white;
    margin: 0 0.5vw 0 0.5vw;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.75vw 2vw;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:not(.active):hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #5336F8;
    border: 1px; 
}

.active {
    border: 1px solid white;
}



.logo {
    font-family: Futura PT;
    float: left;
    font-size: 4vw;
    margin: 2vw 5vw 0 3.5vw;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 550;
}

.logo:hover {
    color: #5336F8;
    text-shadow: 1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
}

// style.css


div.slick-slider {
    // width:100vw;
}

.forss {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.forss .items {
    width: 30vw;
    height: 35vw;
    margin-top: 7vw;
}

.forss .items img {
    width: 24.840625vw;
    height: 31.25vw;
}

.slick-slide {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    
    transition:transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.slick-slide:focus {
        outline: none;
}

div.slick-track {
    margin: 0;
}

div.slick-center {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.15);
    transform: scale(1.15);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#arrows {
    width: 1vw;
    height: 1vw;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;

}

.logo {
    font-family: 'Futura-Normal';
    font-size: 4vw;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2vw;
}

.top  {
    position: absolute;
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 100%;
    transition: opacity 0.15s;
}

.top:hover {
    opacity: 0%;
}

.bottom img {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}


input.prev:focus {
    outline-width: 0;
}

input.next:focus {
    outline-width: 0;
}

.add-on {
    font-family: (var(--font));
    font-size: 1.75vw;
    color: white;
    margin-left: 2vw;
    margin-right: 2vw;
    margin-bottom: 1vw;
}

#inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-bottom: 4vw;
}

#centered {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Slider</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!--style.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1T5ZdOkN6sg2weNQkehStYX2mDo1f0ajJ">
<!--navigation.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1IgyMKG47riH_HmnHoPLH16qhI0UtnK34">

</head>

<body>
    <h2 class="logo">The Lowdown.</h2>

    <ul>
        <li><a  href="text.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="#edition">EDITIONS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#articles">ARTICLES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
        
      </ul>

    <div class="forss">
        <div class="items">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/FWpLzhw/April-Edition-Overlay.png" class="top" alt="" >
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/FbRKb0dt5bz6QOt34jA7jl43XFkHFQf7T0j3wL6b1Z0zSVMNO2DlWl7UAUoTd_dDvCZFhbW822HYyJJQkgH8K0o2dXUrv5uzZl2qrXYF7UWVqqHVinvAqdqz057ULytRu9IE3N0pIw=w2400" class="bottom" alt="">
        </div> 
        <div class="items">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/FWpLzhw/April-Edition-Overlay.png" class="top" alt="" >
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/h2VBt78/May-Edition-Back.png" class="bottom" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="items">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/FWpLzhw/April-Edition-Overlay.png" class="top" alt="" >
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/FbRKb0dt5bz6QOt34jA7jl43XFkHFQf7T0j3wL6b1Z0zSVMNO2DlWl7UAUoTd_dDvCZFhbW822HYyJJQkgH8K0o2dXUrv5uzZl2qrXYF7UWVqqHVinvAqdqz057ULytRu9IE3N0pIw=w2400" class="bottom" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="items">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/FWpLzhw/April-Edition-Overlay.png" class="top" alt="" >
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/h2VBt78/May-Edition-Back.png" class="bottom" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="items">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/FWpLzhw/April-Edition-Overlay.png" class="top" alt="" >
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/FbRKb0dt5bz6QOt34jA7jl43XFkHFQf7T0j3wL6b1Z0zSVMNO2DlWl7UAUoTd_dDvCZFhbW822HYyJJQkgH8K0o2dXUrv5uzZl2qrXYF7UWVqqHVinvAqdqz057ULytRu9IE3N0pIw=w2400" class="bottom" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="inner">
    <div id="centered">
        <input type="image" name="previous" src="https://i.ibb.co/dt3fngT/previous-arrow.png" class="prev" id="arrows" alt="Tool Tip"><span class="add-on">         READ ME         </span><input type="image" name="next" src="https://i.ibb.co/nL7jtPS/next-arrow.png" class="next" id="arrows" alt="Tool Tip">
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1jzlbwu186Lrp0yF_NIcH9Zk2tSFA2PdL"></script>
```